# datepicker() does not display all required dates

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to use the jQuery datepicker to display dates only in Jul and Aug each year, it works except for cutting 31st Aug. I've also tried going from mid Jul to mid Sep, it displays all these days except the 31st Aug regardless.

jQuery

```
    function generateDates(){

        var availableDates = {};

        var startYear = (new Date()).getUTCFullYear();
        var endYear = 2050;

        for(var currentYear = startYear; currentYear <= endYear; currentYear++){

                //Loop over every year from current year to 2050
                for (var d = new Date(currentYear, 7, 1); d <= new Date(currentYear, 8, 31); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {

                    availableDates[d.getUTCFullYear() + "-0" + d.getUTCMonth() + "-" + (d.getUTCDate() <= 9 ? "0" + d.getUTCDate() : d.getUTCDate())] = 1;

                }

        }

        return availableDates;
}

$(function() {
var dates_allowed;



dates_allowed = generateDates();

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    // these aren't necessary, but if you happen to know them, why not
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: new Date(2050, 8, 31),

    // called for every date before it is displayed
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {

        // prepend values lower than 10 with 0
        function addZero(no) {
            if (no < 10){
              return "0" + no;
            }  else {
              return no; 
            }
        }

        var date_str = [
            addZero(date.getFullYear()),
            addZero(date.getMonth() + 1),
            addZero(date.getDate())      
        ].join('-');

        if (dates_allowed[date_str]) {
            return [true, 'good_date', 'This date is available'];
        } else {
            return [false, 'bad_date', 'We are sorry, this date is not available'];
        }
    }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<input id="datepicker" name="startdate" required>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of check every single date you can check if the month of the current date is Jul and Aug using `getMonth` or and the year is <=2050 using `getYear`.

Js date object reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Code:

```
 $(function () {

     $('#datepicker').datepicker({
         // these aren't necessary, but if you happen to know them, why not
         minDate: 0,
         maxDate: new Date(2050, 7, 31),

         // called for every date before it is displayed
         beforeShowDay: function (date) {

             if ((date.getMonth()==6 || date.getMonth()==7) && date.getYear()<=2050) {
                 return [true, 'good_date', 'This date is available'];
             } else {
                 return [false, 'bad_date', 'We are sorry, this date is not available'];
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/EQQrT/

Answer (score 0):

Months are 0-based in JavaScript, so for August you want:

```
new Date(2050, 7, 31)
```

When you set it the month to 8, that's September, so you're trying to say September 31st, which doesn't exist. Similarly you'd want to adjust the index for July.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I tried this and it it moved the problem back to June and July, thanks for replying